# Certificate process IOS developer

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-developer-program

I am still pretty new to IOS development and get quite confused with the apple portal. 
I started a and made a developer cert. Then I went into testing using test flight.com, so I had to make a distribution cert for ad-hoc. So in the app under code signing I have the dev cert for debug and the distribution cert for release. All works fine.

Now I am going to add push notifications with Parse.com. So I have to make another cert to get a ssl for the push notifications. And then when I want to use test flight I have to make another cert for the distribution SSL?

I am so confused. Cant I just have 2 certs? one for developer and one for distribution? And use those to get the SSL for push notifications?

What is the best process here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use distribution certificate for push notification test.

[Upload Guide for iOS. This is 2 yr old post but hope will help you.](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/04/04/list-guideline-for-submitting-iphone-application-to-apple-store/)

Comment: But Because I have one dev cert and one distribution cert for Ad-Hoc use for Test-Flight that means I will need a third for the app store correct?

Comment: for what u need more certificate? If u r going to test push notifications use dist and want to upload the same certificate will use.